# Trouble with a floated div with hidden-* bootstrap class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have the next code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <img src="images/w2.png" alt="W logo" class="center-block visible-xs-block visible-sm-inline-block visible-md-inline-block visible-lg-inline-block">

        <h2 class="center-block visible-xs-block visible-sm-inline-block visible-md-inline-block visible-lg-inline-block">This is h2 header</h2>

        <div class="hidden-xs visible-sm-inline-block visible-md-inline-block visible-lg-inline-block pull-right">

            <div class="row">
                <img src="images/user.png" alt="User image" class="col-sm-3 img-circle">
                <span class="col-sm-9">Non register user</span>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn default btn-large col-sm-6">Log in</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn default btn-large col-sm-6">Register</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

The above code just show a div which have inside it a image with 50x50px and a h2 and another floated div by the .pull-right class. My problem appear when the viewport size come to set more than extra-small size (xs); the floated div disappear in xs size (at this point everything works well) but later when the viewport come to be small (sm) or higher, the floated div appear in another line: just below from the img and h2.

How can I solve this? thank you.

Edit the question above:

The behavior which I'm looking for is that the div.hidden-xs appear only when the viewport have more size than extra-small size (xs) and also that it appear horizontally aligned to the right (right float) at the same line of img and h2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if `<div class="hidden-xs visible-sm-inline-block visible-md-inline-block visible-lg-inline-block pull-right">` is troubling you, that is because you only put class `hidden-xs`. Because that class means only hidden if viewport is xs. On the other hand, you put `visible-sm-inline-block` and `visible-md-inline-block`, so of course that `div` appear below the `img` and `h2`.

reference: [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Why don't you try

```
<div class="hidden-xs pull-right">
```

EDIT:
reference: [learnlayout](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)

I think I've got the wrong concept before, sorry. I think your `<img>` and  `<h2>` not inside the `<div>` with class `visible-*-*`.

Comment: Thank you for your response and attention. I had edited the question; I miss more details. What I´m looking for is that the div.hidden-xs appear only when de viewport have more than xs size and also appear at the same line of img and h2 elements.